# jQuery how to get inner Object from Object an make a SUM on one item

Tags: jquery, ajax

From this `order` object, I want to extract a particular property from each of the objects in the `products` array.

```
var order = {
  "products": [
    {
      "product_name":"Name",
      "product_sku":"000000075266",
      "pricesUnformatted":5130,
      "prices":"5.130 EUR",
      "subtotal":5130,
      "subtotal_tax_amount":0,
      "subtotal_discount":0,
      "subtotal_with_tax":5130,
      "quantity":18
    },
    {
      "product_name":"Name2",
      "product_sku":"000000072312",
      "pricesUnformatted":369,
      "prices":"369 EUR",
      "subtotal":369,
      "subtotal_tax_amount":0,
      "subtotal_discount":0,
      "subtotal_with_tax":369,
      "quantity":1
    }
  ],
  "totalProduct":19,
  "billTotal":"<div class='cart_left'>TotalPrice<\/div> : <strong>6.826 EUR<\/strong>",
  "dataValidated":false,
  "totalProductTxt":"<div class='cart_left'>Quantity<\/div> <div class='cart_right'><strong>19<\/strong><\/div>"
}
```

So from this object I want to get the "subtotal_with_tax" items and than SUM them and of course print the result because the "billTotal" contains the shipping price which I don't need and I can't modify the code before I get this object.

I tryed to make it work but I'm stuck at This point because I don't know how to target a specific item's value like in this case "subtotal_with_tax" :

```
$.each(order.products, function(key, val) {
  $.each(val, function(key, val) {});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var subtotals_with_tax = 0;

$.each( order.products, function( index, product ) {

  subtotals_with_tax += product.subtotal_with_tax;

} );
```

As @eicto said, if you only care about browsers that support it, or are using a "polyfill" for `map()`, or ES5 methods in general, in other browsers, by all means use `map()`:

```
var subtotals_with_tax = 0;

order.products.map( function( product ) {

  subtotals_with_tax += product.subtotal_with_tax;

} );
```

Comment: As you said I have an object called "Obj" with the "products" property and I just wanted to highlight that this is the "Obj" object, I'm sorry if it's misleading. And of course Thank you very much your code worked perfect.

Comment: Ok, thanks, you're welcome. I edited your question so that the object is assigned to an `order` var, and so that the other code uses that same var name. (The edit has to be approved or it won't be visible.)

Answer (score 0):

just use map() it is not jquery

```
var sttotal=0;
order.products.map(function(a){sttotal+=a.subtotal_with_tax})
```